# javascript call function on remote server and execute function on that server

Tags: javascript, function

I have a html page on a web server (it's a remote outlet programmable via LAN) with a js script included. I need to execute a function declared on this .js from a remote server php's page.
I cannot understand how to do and if it's possible.
thank you
roberto

Comment: One way I can think of is using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets).

Comment: Simple AJAX calls will likely solve your problem.  If you need to go cross-domain, use CORS.

Comment: Hi,thank you for fast reply. I'm not very skilled could you please give me an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not allowed because of the security issue.
You can see what is possible here:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iFrame.

When your user opens the php page, it will contain an iframe that opens the html page of the other web server.

Here's a stackoverflow question that answers how to do that [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

if you don't want the iframe to be visible you can hide with CSS.